# Check media pipeline on kurento media server

Tags: webrtc, kurento

How can I check media pipeline on kurento media server in real time. And how many media pipelines open or close

Comment: Haven't interacted with media server yet but perhaps checking logs may help you: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get statistics and existing pipelines/elements through Kurento's ServerManager class ([Java docs](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.7.1/_static/client-javadoc/org/kurento/client/ServerManager.html), [JS docs](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.7.1/_static/client-jsdoc/module-core_abstracts.ServerManager.html)).  That class contains a method called `getPipelines`

An example of implementing the Server Manager can be seen in the [Kurento Monitor](https://github.com/mariogasparoni/kurento-monitor/) project.